# Reverse int golang

Tags: indexing, go, int

How to change `12345` to `54321`?
With a string, you can change the string to a `rune`, and reverse it, but you cannot do the same for an integer. I have searched and found no one talking about this. Examples
`131415` >>> `514131`
`1357` >>> `7531`
`123a` >>> **ERROR**
 -EDIT-
I was thinking, why not create a `slice` and index that?
Then I realized that you can't index `int`
(http://play.golang.org/p/SUSg04tZsc)
**MY NEW QUESTION IS**
How do you index an int?
**OR**
How do you reverse a int?

Comment: Is indexing an `int` a requirement? Because you can reverse an `int` without indexing and it is more straight forward in my opinion.

Comment: It is not. Please share your non-complicated way

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is a solution that does not use indexing an `int`

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func reverse_int(n int) int {
    new_int := 0
    for n > 0 {
        remainder := n % 10
        new_int *= 10
        new_int += remainder 
        n /= 10
    }
    return new_int 
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(reverse_int(123456))
    fmt.Println(reverse_int(100))
    fmt.Println(reverse_int(1001))
    fmt.Println(reverse_int(131415))
    fmt.Println(reverse_int(1357))
}
```

Result:

```
654321
1
1001
514131
7531
```

[Go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/CyGd7Hq3DV)

Comment: Is there a reason not to just convert the integer to a string and then reverse it?  I came up with a different solution, but as a newbie to Go figured I might have missed something compared to how you did it.

Comment: Gophers like to avoid pulling in more packages than necessary or using more memory than necessary.  And if the code is going to run so often that cpu time or power consumed is an issue, they would opt for keeping the solution in the integer domain - also fewer error cases to cover.  Most conversions from integer to string are going to use a loop that does its own modulus 10 in each iteration under the covers.  Then a loop that reverses the string.  Then a loop that builds up an integer by multiplying by 10. Asking the computer to do too much busy work.  And what about negative ints?

Comment: This won't work correctly if the number ends in any amount of 0s. For example 19100 becomes 191.

Comment: Also doesn't work well with negative integers. If you change `for n > 0 {` to `for n != 0 {` that fixes the issue with negative integers (tested).

Answer (score 4):

I converted the integer to a string, reverse the string, and convert the result back to a string.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {

    fmt.Println(reverse_int(123456))
        fmt.Println(reverse_int(100))
        fmt.Println(reverse_int(1001))
        fmt.Println(reverse_int(131415))
        fmt.Println(reverse_int(1357))

}

func reverse_int(value int) int {

    intString := strconv.Itoa(value)

    newString := ""

    for x := len(intString); x > 0; x-- {
        newString += string(intString[x - 1])
    }

    newInt, err := strconv.Atoi(newString)

    if(err != nil){
        fmt.Println("Error converting string to int")
    }

    return newInt
}
```

Comment: Another option is use a rune array,  `r := make([]rune, len(intString))`, to avoid `+=` on strings (due to immutability). After that `string(r)` will convert the array to string.

Answer (score 4):

Very similar to the first answer but this checks to make sure you don't go out of bounds on the type.

```
func reverse(x int) int {    
    rev := 0
    for x != 0 {
        pop := x % 10
        x /=  10
        if rev > math.MaxInt32/10 || (rev == math.MaxInt32 /10 && pop > 7) {
            return 0
        }
        if rev < math.MinInt32/10 || (rev == math.MinInt32/10 && pop < -8) {
            return 0
        }
        rev = rev * 10 + pop
    }

    return rev
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Also flips negative numbers **int**

```
func Abs(x int) int {
  if x < 0 {
    return -x
  }
   return x
}

func reverse_int(n int) int {
  newInt := 0
  sign := 1
   if n < 0 {
    sign = -1
   }
   n = Abs(n)
  for n > 0 {
    remainder := n % 10
    newInt = newInt*10 + remainder
    n /= 10
  }
  return newInt * sign 
}

func main() {
  fmt.Println(reverse_int(-100))
  fmt.Println(reverse_int(-1001))
  fmt.Println(reverse_int(131415))
  fmt.Println(reverse_int(1357))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Fokiruna's answer but also checks for a 32bit overflow

```
func reverse(x int) int {
    result, sign := 0, 1
 
    if(x < 0) {
        sign = -1
        x = -x     
    }

    for x > 0 {
        remainder := x % 10;
        result = result * 10 + remainder
        x = x/10
    }
    
    var checkInt int = int(int32(result))

    if checkInt != result {
        return 0
    }

    return result * sign
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
package main

import "fmt"

func reverse(x int) int {
    num := x
    returnValue := 0
    if num < 0 {
        num *= -1
    }
    for num > 0 {
        returnValue = (returnValue * 10) + (num % 10)
        num /= 10
    }
    if x < 0 {
        returnValue *= -1
    }
    return returnValue
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(reverse(1235))
}
```

Live code - https://go.dev/play/p/_KvYAzGb5Dg